# Cancel NSMutableRequest and XMLParsing method ObjectiveC

Tags: objective-c, xml-parsing, ios-4.2, nsurlrequest

I need to cancel a NSMutableRequest and a XMLParsing if the user choose another view

I do this on ViewDidLoad:

```
NSMutableURLRequest * req = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:endereco]
                                                        cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:20.0f];

conn = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:req delegate:self];

[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;

if(conn)
{
    receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
    [DSBezelActivityView newActivityViewForView:self.view withLabel:@"Obtendo Lista..."];
}
```

I know i have to : `[conn cancel];` on viewWillDisappear, but how i can check i the connection is ocurring so i can cancel it?
And the same happens to the parse method :

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;

    NSXMLParser * parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithData:receivedData];
    [parser setDelegate:self];
    [parser parse];
    [parser release];
    [receivedData release];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using two flags(`BOOL` variables). One flag will keep track of connection activity(whether connection is still in progress or has `finishedLoading`).

So, for connection (`BOOL isConnectionActive`)
set `isConnectionActive = YES` in `viewDidLoad`
and set it `isConnectionActive = NO` in `connectionDidFinishLoading` or `connectionDidFailWithError` delegate methods.
and check

```
if(isConnectionActive)
{
if(con != nil)
{
 [con cancel];
}
  isConnectionActive=NO;
}
```

in `viewWillApear`: method.

similar thing you can do for xmlParsing. you will set `isParsingCompleted=NO` 
`- (void)parserDidStartDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser` method.
and `isParsingCompleted=YES`

```
- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser;

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser parseErrorOccurred:(NSError *)parseError;
```

methods and you will use

```
if(!isParsingCompleted)
{
if (parser!= nil)
{
   [parser abortParsing];
}
 isParsingCompleted=YES;
}
```

in `viewWillApear:` method.[for this you will need a class level reference for parser.]

Thanks,